# Is there a possible way to add back pointer to parent in tree structure?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-tree

I'm trying to make a structure that looks like a binary tree. Where do I need to set up the back pointers so every node can linked to it's parent and how will this affect on the performance?

```
function Node(expression, trueStatement, falseStatement) {
    this.expression = expression;
    this.trueStatement = trueStatement
    this.falseStatement = falseStatement
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.back = null;
}

function BinarySearchTree() {
    this.root = null;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.push = function(state, expression, trueStatement, falseStatement) {
    var root = this.root;

    if (trueStatement == "") {
        trueStatement = false;
    }
    if (falseStatement == "") {
        falseStatement = false;
    }

    if (!root) {
        this.root = new Node(expression, trueStatement, falseStatement);
        return;
    }



    var currentNode = root;
    var newNode = new Node(expression, trueStatement, falseStatement);

    while (currentNode) {
        if (state) {
            if (!currentNode.left) {
                currentNode.left = newNode;
                break;
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            }
        } else {
            if (!currentNode.right) {
                currentNode.right = newNode;
                break;
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
            }
        }
    }

}
var bst = new BinarySearchTree();
bst.push(true, "IIF()", "", "@user");
bst.push(false, "IIF()1", "@user", "");
bst.push(true, "IIF()2", "@user", "");
```

The goal is every node should be linked to them parents.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "binary tree parent link", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property parent/back to your Node object and populate when you are creating Node.
and where you have

```
currentNode.left = newNode;
```

also add

```
 currentNode.left = newNode;
 newNode.back = currentNode;
```

Implement the same logic other places